# Probability distribution function in Python

Tags: python, numpy, probability, histogram

I know how to create an histogram in Python, but I would like that it is the probability density distribution.

Let's start with my example. I have an array `d`, with a size of 500000 elements. With the following code I am building a simple histogram telling me how many elements of my array `d` are between every bin.

```
max_val=log10(max(d))
min_val=log10(min(d))

logspace = np.logspace(min_val, max_val, 50)
H=hist(select,bins=logspace,histtype='step')
```

The problem is that this plot is not what I want. I would like to have the probability distribution function of my array `d`. Instead of having the number of elements of my array which are within every bins, I would like to have the probability of them being in that bin. I tried with normed=True, but that seems not working since I have bins which are equally logspaced.

Comment: By `50.0000` did you mean 50000? 500000?

Comment: You are probably using `hist` from matplotlib, not `histogram` from numpy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what your `hist` function is. If you're using NumPy's `histogram`, try setting `density=True`. See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html .

Comment: Matteo is probably using `hist` from matplotlib, not `histogram` from numpy.

Comment: Yes, I am using hist from matplotlib. I tried with histogram from numpy with density=True but I got this error: TypeError: histogram() got an unexpected keyword argument 'density'

Comment: I got that error as well but it was fixed by updating to numpy 1.6.1.